# How to deal with dates using record section formula in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report report in visual studio 2012. I want to access the data between two dates from database using record section formula. What would be the formula for it?

Comment: have you tried any code? can show here

Answer (score 0):

Try to use crosstab to display data base on its date and it will group your data display by it date try to look at this [crystal report croosstab](http://www.reportsyouneed.com/blog/understanding-crystal-cross-tabs-part-1)